# Show users presence status of Cisco Jabber in web page

Tags: xmpp, status, cisco

I want to fetch the presence status of any users connected to Cisco Jabber IM.

The status can be *online*, *offline* and *away*.

Could anyone tell me the API to achieve this?

Answer (score 1):

I think this question is better suited to the Cisco Communities forum, but the answer is that you should use the **Jabber SDK (CAXL)** for this.  JavaScript-based.

[Jabber SDK IM and Presence (CAXL) FAQ](http://Jabber%20SDK%20IM%20and%20Presence%20(CAXL)%20FAQ)

From the FAQ:

> In short, the capabilities include: All the basic XMPP features for
>   contacts, groups, sending and receiving messages and presence status

The community forum for Jabber can be found here:

[communities.cisco.com Jabber Community](https://communities.cisco.com/community/developer/jabber)